# Arangodb AQL similar to NOT IN of SQL

Tags: arangodb, aql

How to do a `FILTER` like this SQL example in AQL?

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE option NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In v2.3 and above, it is possible to do:

```
FOR doc IN test 
  FILTER doc.option NOT IN [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
  RETURN doc
```

In earlier versions, the following should work:

```
FOR doc IN test 
  FILTER ! (doc.option IN [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ])
  RETURN doc
```

Comment: It works, but would be nice to have an alias for `!` > `NOT(...)`. Even better would be a python-like construct `NOT IN`, so you can type the way you speak / think and avoid parentheses.

Comment: a `NOT IN` construct will come in ArangoDB release 2.3 or 2.4, which contains some major AQL rewrites.